# Disabling relativenumber in Command Mode

Tags: command-line, autocmd

I have

```
  au InsertEnter * set norelativenumber
  au InsertLeave * set relativenumber
```

So that I have relativenumber in normal mode but not insert mode. I want to extend this to command mode. I tried

```
  au CmdLineEnter * set norelativenumber
  au CmdlineLeave * set relativenumber
```

But these don't work. Under `h CmdLineEnter`, it says

> ```
> <afile> is set to the |cmdline-char|.
> ```

So I think it's setting `norelativenumber` on the `:` "file", which isn't my actual buffer. How do I get it to set `norelativenumber` on the buffer I entered the command line *from*?

I'm on neovim 0.4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
au CmdLineEnter * set norelativenumber | redraw
au CmdlineLeave * set relativenumber
```

Edit: apparently the window does not redraw while you are in the command mode, so you need to force the redraw explicitly to get the effect of the command to be shown. And apparently you also do not need `| redraw` for `CmdlineLeave` case, because when you leave the command line mode, you're back in the window, and it redraws automatically (so I've removed the second `| redraw` in the example above, leaving it only for `CmdLineEnter`)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! If you know *why* this works, an [edit] with the explanation would be awesome :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I'm not an expert in vimscript. First I thought that this was about the `rno` command not being executed in the correct window, so I've concocted a function that did `execute(winnr() . 'windo ' . a:cmd)` to execute `set rno`/`sent norno` commands. But then it too didn't work. After experimenting it became clear that comands are executed in correct window, but just that the view of the window didn't change. Then I thought that maybe it just do not redraw while I am in a command mode. Added `redraw` and it worked, and it turned out the function with `windo` is not needed